# AOSP 11 - Without Display - AKA Headless Mode

Tags: android-source, headless, android-11

Is there a way to build/run AOSP 11 in a headless mode? Couldn't find any Android documentation detailing how to run an AOSP without a display. for example, the documentation here details how to run Android with more than 2 displays, https://source.android.com/devices/tech/display/multi_display/displays

I am building on ASOP 11, specifically [Omni ROM](http://github.com/omnirom/android.git). Tried running the RPi4 without a display and didn't boot completely.

Any idea where to modify the codebase or settings to run it headless other than using a dummy display adapter?

Comment: Hi Jimson, did you manage to get this working? I am actually looking into how to do this as well. Lmk if you have found some ways of getting it to run.

Comment: Nope. The only way I found is to use dummy HDMI plug with RPi.

Comment: I had just come across this, mind you it is quite old. Android 4.4 based. https://github.com/gibsson/headless-android

Will see and try if I can make something out of it.

Comment: Fwiw, I managed to get this working on Raspberry Pi, here's a quick guide/reference if you are interested.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/73054376/260245