# How to build Android 10 AOSP without display (headless device)

Tags: android, android-source, headless

We are trying to build Android 10 without display or GUI. Is it possible to add dummy display adaptor so that it will work without actual physical display. Any reference code will be helpful.  In our device we don't have LCD or touch screen. Basically we want full android stack without DISPLAY.
I have referred some of the topics related to headless device which was supported in older android version, but those are applicable for older android version.

Comment: Why?  The point of the OS is the UI.  Without that its pretty pointless, and for a lot of purposes actually makes life harder (for example, killing of background processes).  Why wouldn't you just build an embedded Linux machine?

Comment: I understand, that's the good point. But our customer device does not have display and they want  to make use of Android only. All applications will be running in background without any GUI.  Something like embedded Android with Java services. (Android full stack minus DISPLAY)

Comment: "All applications will be running in the background" doesn't really work on Android.  It's counter to everything about it.  You would need a VERY customized AOSP build that removes pretty much all power management code, especially DOZE mode and all the service killing code.  And you'd have to maintain it in an OS going the exact opposite way.  This is when a good engineer pushes back and tells their client that its the wrong solution.

Comment: We are fully aware of these complexities.  But customer pushes back and asking for solution as they already finalized Android platform for their product due to their own secret reasons !  So we just asked if someone already tried this customization or if any easier option to just disable DISPLAY, which will save our time and effort.  Anyway thanks for your suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

as sheer luck, I ran into your post. I had just gone thru this exercise myself.

Here's a reference on how you can get headless setup, especially you are using Android 10, this reference matches the version you are using.
https://www.opersys.com/blog/android-10-on-beaglebone-black/

I was able to follow the guide and used Android 12L on Raspberry Pi 4 - I started using this Android Rpi project as reference, and take out display/gpu.
https://github.com/android-rpi

Comment: Thanks a lot.  We will try this approach.

Comment: @mohdyusuf do you mind explaining it in detail Thanks for confirming it worked with 12L on rpi4.

Comment: @JimsonJames, you would need kernel 5.10 based from 'android-rpi' project I mentioned above. I am seeing an issue w/ VKMS driver in kernel 5.4. You will need to change GPU/display stack to SwiftShader for software OpenGL emulation - this is the reference https://github.com/peyo-hd/local_manifests/tree/swiftshader . Please send thank you to that developer, he helped me. Next you have to add CONFIG_DRM_VKMS=y in the kernel config and rebuild. Android 12L has default support for VMKS driver detection in android. Android 10, you would need to follow Opersys' changes in <aosp>/hardware/.

Comment: In vc4-kms-v3d-pi4.dtb, disable all vc4/gpu/hdmi nodes so that you properly disable display hardware.

Comment: @mohdyusuf I'm planning on testing it on Android 12L like you did. So Kernel version shouldn't be a problem. Thank You Sir!